# Show a number of listview items in my TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

How can I display number of items off a listview in my textview?
Here is a picture of my activity_main.xml:

[Mainactivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkvbq.png)

Textview Verktøy inn/Utlånstatus opens one activity with a listview. I want the number of listview items displayed in my textview. Is that possible?

Adapter:

```
public class listVerktoy extends ArrayAdapter<Verktoy> {

private Activity context;
private List<Verktoy> listverktoy;





public listVerktoy(Activity context, List<Verktoy> listverktoy){
    super (context, R.layout.list_verktoy, listverktoy);
    this.context = context;
    this.listverktoy = listverktoy;



}
public List<Verktoy> getItems(){
    return listverktoy;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();



    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_verktoy, null, true);

    TextView tvverktøynavn = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøynavn);
    TextView tvverktøynr = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøynr);
    TextView tvverktøytype = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøytype);
    TextView tvverktøystatus = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøystatus);
    TextView tvutlånttil = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvutlånttil);



    Verktoy verktoy = listverktoy.get(position);

    tvverktøynavn.setText(verktoy.getVerktøynavn());
    tvverktøynr.setText(verktoy.getVerktøynr());
    tvverktøytype.setText(verktoy.getVerktøytype());
    tvverktøystatus.setText(verktoy.getVerktøystatus());
    tvutlånttil.setText(verktoy.getUtlånttil());

    return listViewItem;


}
```

Here is my "mainactivity":

```
public class Verktoyside extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
TextView verktøyliste;
TextView verktøyut;
TextView verktøyinn;
TextView tvdate;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verktoyside);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ALMU");

    verktøyliste = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvverktøyliste);
    verktøyliste.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent verktøyliste = new Intent(Verktoyside.this, Verktoyliste.class);
            startActivity(verktøyliste);
        }
    });

    verktøyut = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvutlånverktøy);
    verktøyut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent verktøyut = new Intent(Verktoyside.this, Utlanside.class);
            startActivity(verktøyut);
        }
    });
    verktøyinn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvinnleververktøy);
    verktøyinn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent verktøyinn = new Intent(Verktoyside.this, Innleveringside.class);
            startActivity(verktøyinn);
        }
    });



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hovedside, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Instillinger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What are you using to fill the list view adapter? An array? the length of the array would be your number of items.

Comment: I use arrayadapter. But how can I get the number to show in my textview?

Comment: Show your MainActivity code, I'll help you

Comment: Just edited my question with my mainactivity code. Do you need anything else?

Comment: create a `TextView` that will display your text then do this `your_textview.setText(listverktoy.size());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `TextView` that will display your text then do this `your_textview.setText(listverktoy.size());`

Comment: Hi, does this work if I get my listview items from Firebase database? And I have different activities that show different filtered listview (listverktoy). How can I show the number of items of a filtered listview?

Comment: If your items are stored in your `Verktoy` class from firebase. I think you can. If you want to show your number of items in different activities. You need to have conditions.

Comment: Conditions, do you have an example for that?